# How to fix 'Bulk load data conversion error' when bulk loading a datetime from csv into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert, sql-server-2019

I'm using SQL Server 2019 running on Fedora 32. I'm attempting to bulk load rows from a csv file to a table using a format file. The operation is erroring and I can't see exactly where I have gone wrong.

Below I will post all relevant info;

Table layout:

```
create table flow_data_test
(
    id              BIGINT,
    USERNAME        varchar(25),
    FIRST_SWITCHED  BIGINT,
    LAST_SWITCHED   BIGINT,
    IN_BYTES        BIGINT,
    IN_PKTS         BIGINT,
    INPUT_SNMP      BIGINT,
    OUTPUT_SNMP     BIGINT,
    IPV4_SRC_ADDR   BIGINT,
    IPV4_DST_ADDR   BIGINT,
    PROTOCOL        SMALLINT,
    SRC_TOS         SMALLINT,
    L4_SRC_PORT     INT,
    L4_DST_PORT     INT,
    FLOW_SAMPLER_ID SMALLINT,
    IPV4_NEXT_HOP   BIGINT,
    DST_MASK        SMALLINT,
    SRC_MASK        SMALLINT,
    TCP_FLAGS       SMALLINT,
    DIRECTION       SMALLINT,
    TIMESTAMP       datetime
);
```

SQL statement:

```
bulk insert flow_data_test
    from '/var/opt/mssql/flow_data_test.csv'
    WITH
    (
        BATCHSIZE =1000000,
        FORMATFILE = '/var/opt/mssql/flow_data_test_format_file.fmt'
    );
```

Format file:

```
9.0
20
1       SQLCHAR         0       25      ""      2       USERNAME        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLBIGINT       0       8       ""      3       FIRST_SWITCHED  ""
3       SQLBIGINT       0       8       ""      4       LAST_SWITCHED   ""
4       SQLBIGINT       0       8       ""      5       IN_BYTES        ""
5       SQLBIGINT       0       8       ""      6       IN_PKTS         ""
6       SQLBIGINT       0       8       ""      7       INPUT_SNMP      ""
7       SQLBIGINT       0       8       ""      8       OUTPUT_SNMP     ""
8       SQLBIGINT       0       8       ""      9       IPV4_SRC_ADDR   ""
9       SQLBIGINT       0       8       ""      10      IPV4_DST_ADDR   ""
10      SQLSMALLINT     0       2       ""      11      PROTOCOL        ""
11      SQLSMALLINT     0       2       ""      12      SRC_TOS         ""
12      SQLINT          0       4       ""      13      L4_SRC_PORT     ""
13      SQLINT          0       4       ""      14      L4_DST_PORT     ""
14      SQLSMALLINT     0       2       ""      15      FLOW_SAMPLER_ID ""
15      SQLBIGINT       0       8       ""      16      IPV4_NEXT_HOP   ""
16      SQLSMALLINT     0       2       ""      17      DST_MASK        ""
17      SQLSMALLINT     0       2       ""      18      SRC_MASK        ""
18      SQLSMALLINT     0       2       ""      19      TCP_FLAGS       ""
19      SQLSMALLINT     0       2       ""      20      DIRECTION       ""
20      SQLDATETIME     0       26      "\n"    21      TIMESTAMP       ""
```

Sample data:

```
800000000000005,2984550538,2984602468,19210,39,1,2,178363049,875581251,6,0,60643,37430,0,2886991873,0,16,27,1,2019-11-01 10:11:12
800000000000003,2984553124,2984602120,1272,17,1,2,178360509,1410770606,6,0,52291,2015,0,2886991873,0,16,24,1,2019-11-01 10:11:12
800000000000007,2984579614,2984602288,389,7,2,1,1055450321,178375854,6,72,12051,53540,0,3104344062,16,0,26,0,2019-11-01 10:11:12
800000000000007,2984579882,2984602042,176,4,1,2,178372684,3109042104,6,0,80,62947,0,2886991873,0,16,18,1,2019-11-01 10:11:12
800000000000006,2984579908,2984602248,176,4,1,2,178372683,3109042017,6,0,80,42501,0,2886991873,0,16,18,1,2019-11-01 10:11:12
800000000000005,2984579976,2984602350,176,4,1,2,178372676,3109042035,6,0,80,33873,0,2886991873,0,16,18,1,2019-11-01 10:11:12
800000000000009,2984580118,2984602590,176,4,1,2,178372769,3109042079,6,0,80,59325,0,2886991873,0,16,18,1,2019-11-01 10:11:12
800000000000005,2984580262,2984602126,176,4,1,2,178372682,96141838,6,0,80,64698,0,2886991873,0,16,18,1,2019-11-01 10:11:12
800000000000003,2984580422,2984602594,176,4,1,2,178372680,96141914,6,0,80,33478,0,2886991873,0,16,18,1,2019-11-01 10:11:12
800000000000004,2984580428,2984602710,176,4,1,2,178372681,3109041881,6,0,80,46583,0,2886991873,0,16,18,1,2019-11-01 10:11:12
```

Example error:

> [S0001][4864] Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 20 (TIMESTAMP).

I thought maybe the issue was with the text formatting on the datetime, so I tested it in an insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO flow_data_test(USERNAME, FIRST_SWITCHED, LAST_SWITCHED, IN_BYTES, IN_PKTS, INPUT_SNMP, OUTPUT_SNMP,
                           IPV4_SRC_ADDR, IPV4_DST_ADDR, PROTOCOL, SRC_TOS, L4_SRC_PORT, L4_DST_PORT, FLOW_SAMPLER_ID,
                           IPV4_NEXT_HOP, DST_MASK, SRC_MASK, TCP_FLAGS, DIRECTION, TIMESTAMP)
VALUES ('username', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '2019-11-01 10:11:12')
```

This works as expected.

Ideally a solution would not be to use an intermediate conversion table as I have roughly 1.5 billion rows to import.

One more thing to note is that the format file was not generated using the bcp tool, it was written by hand, so I'm expecting the issue to be there.

Comment: Well `timestamp` is a reserved word - it's an SQL Server data type. If you were using the `bcp.exe` utility you'd use the `-q` switch.

Comment: Should you not specify column delimiters (comas) in your format file? See example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#creating-a-non-xml-format-file

Comment: @Alex It's not obligatory. If unspecified they default to comma.